# Why is the base peak of my MS spectra of 2,3,5-tribromothiophene at m/z=382?

Tags: mass-spectrometry

I recently requested a ESI-MS analysis of 2,3,5-tribromothiophene and got this spectrum:

[image: MS analysis of 2,3,5-tribromothiophene]

These are the analysis conditions:

- Detector: ESI(+)
- Source Tem: 150
- Capillary voltage: 1.5 kV
- Cone Voltage: 20 V
- Mass range: 200 - 1000
- Flow: 0.2 mL/min
- mobile phase: 0.1% formic acid:acetonitrile (50:50)

The sample was dissolved in methanol. Below is the spectrum of methanol:

[image: MS spectrum of methanol]

The molecular weight of 2,3,5-tribromothiophene is 320.83 g/mol. But why does the base peak occur at m/z=382 and what are higher m/z peaks like m/z=423 and 740? I can't interpret the result at all.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128375/discussion-on-question-by-krang-lee-why-is-the-base-peak-of-my-ms-spectra-of-2-3).