# Bromine isotope peaks were observed in EI-MS, but not in ESI-MS

Tags: mass-spectrometry

I have been conducting a synthesis involving 2,3,5-tribromothiophene. Because I thought that desired product doesn't have so small molecular weight, I decided to use ESI instead of EI, and so I also requested ESI-MS experiment of 2,3,5-tribromothiohpene as a standard. In that time I got somewhat weird spectrum ([Why is the base peak of my MS spectra of 2,3,5-tribromothiophene at m/z=382?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/155648/why-is-the-base-peak-of-my-ms-spectra-of-2-3-5-tribromothiophene-at-m-z-382)). Below are the ESI-MS spectra of 2,3,5-tribromothiophene, and methanol which was used as solvent to insert it to the MS instrument, respectively.

[image: ESI-MS spectrum of 2,3,5-tribromothiophene]
[image: ESI-MS spectrum of methanol]

Recently, I made a hypothesis that since 2,3,5-tribromothiohpene was purchased at around 2019, it may decomposed in long-term storage and produced strange spectrum. To verify this, I requested a EI-MS experiment and in this time I got a reasonable spectrum that has clear isotope peaks.

[image: EI-MS spectrum of 2,3,5-tribromothiophene]

What is the problem with ESI-MS? May the operator miss some settings of the instrument? In fact, I have never observed any isotope peaks whenever I requested ESI-MS experiments of my reaction mixture. As a client, are there any instrument settings that I can request to the analyzer? For what it's worth, the model of the instrument is Xevo TQ-S micro.

Comment: They probably have used acetic acid erozol for electrospray so malecular peak would have been (.M + AcOH).

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne But still there are no isotope peaks for 3 Br's.

Comment: Can you post your ESI-MS as well so we can look at it?

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Added it to the post.

Comment: Cannot see peaks around 80 m/z to find out bromine is eliminated. There is anothe peak next to 382 m/z peak. My geuss is two bormine atoms must have eliminated.

Comment: Unfortunately putting a bounty on question also attracts spam and trolling behaviour. Please raise a flag for that so that we can counteract this. Apart from this ignore it for the time being, as it will be deleted in due time.

Comment: You might already know this, but her we go anyway. There is currently a proposal for a more specialised site for [mass spectrometry](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126894/mass-spectrometry?referrer=MDdiZGEwNDNmMTVjYTU2ZDdhNjM4OWY0NzE4NWYwODA0MzA4Y2RlYzdlNDU2NDEwNWMwNjdhYmJmMzlmMGQyZVh0WYeYH8WU-ZTLpqwRws2cuL09nvPf7RliryCVBtCh0). I think this question might be a good fit, and you might want to support this proposal.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Thank you. I didn't know the site for mass spectrometry exist. I will delete this post about 2 hours later.

Comment: @Martin-マーチンOh... Excuse me, but how can I retrieve the bounty? Just have to wait? I can't delete the post.

Comment: Currently the site for mass spectrometry is only a proposal. Your question is fine here, as is the bounty, but for the future you might be interested in the new proposal. Please don't delete it, just wait and hope someone is able to answer it.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Ah, I see. I misunderstood the thing you said.

Comment: ***https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/163871/bromine-isotope-peaks-were-observed-in-ei-ms-but-not-in-esi-ms***